# Unity iOS Build size is way big

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, 2d

Currently I'm on the verge of making a 2D puzzle game for **iOS**. When I zip my project it's size become **16MB** approximately. When I build it in **xcode** the project size become **780MB** and when I archive it then it becomes **1.5GB**.

But the real problem begins when I upload it to test flight for internal and external testing then in iTunes connect it's compressed size became **143MB** and **Universal install size** become **285MB** and for different iPhone install size become **160MB** in average. Now I think 160MB is very large install file for a simple 2D puzzle game and can cause major drop outs when I publish it.

Unity version: 5.4.2

Scripting backend : IL2CPP

Api compatibility Level: .Net 2.0 subnet

Can anyone tell me what can I do to solve this problem, or the size will reduce when I'll publish it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you follow everything explained here?: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/iphone-playerSizeOptimization.html

Comment: The zipped size of Unity project is not a good indicator for your final ipa size.

Unity adds its own runtime, which from my experience is about 20 MB, this means that even with an empty Unity project you'll get a 20 MB. 

That being said having a project that ends up at 160 MB is unusual. Can you provide a link to the project?

Comment: When you unzip the .ipa file and look at the contents, you can sort of figure out what specifically is causing this size. How big is the `Data` folder inside of the .ipa for example?

Answer (score 11):

To solve that (My app was 1.7 GB for iOS, while Android's apk file is just 50 MB) I changed the compression method for Unity build:

```
Build Settings -> Compression Method -> LZ4HC
```

Now it is just ~80MB (instead of 1.7 GB). Hope it helps someone.

Comment: You just saved my game! Thank you so much. It is really useful!

Comment: I can't see the Compression Method in Unity 2020.1.4f1 iOS build setting.
Can you please let me know where it is?

Answer (score 0):

This is my checklist for reducing file size of APK I guess it applies to iOS.

1. Removing duplicate or unused assets
2. Reducing sprite sizes (power of 4 for iOS)
3. Reducing SFX sample rate and bit rate (mono, vorbis, 44100)
4. Using Texture Compression for sprites (16 bit is better. and disable mipmaps)
5. Removing external assemblies (and most of .NET references)
6. Using pngopt to strip out the unnecessary informations from PNG files

Comment: Thanks for helping, but I've already done all of this. I think it's something to do with xcode :(

Comment: I don't xcode but I think step 5 is responsible. maybe you used an assembly causing lots of required dlls get into the build.