# Unity3d game takes up too large size in ios

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I created a simple casual game with Unity3d, but its installation size is not as "casual" as it looks. It takes up around 200MB in my iphone. This is unbelievable to me. Because image and audio resources it uses are no more than 50MB. Then I exported this game with an empty scene. However, it still reached 140MB. But if I create a new empty project, it only takes up 30 to 40MB. I have no idea which part goes wrong. Why is an empty scene so different with an empty project in terms of installation size. Does it have anything to do with that I imported a variety of assets and plugins from assets store? But I remember as long as I do not use them in the project, it should not affect the file size. Can anyone give me any hint to this issue?

Comment: See if [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41658456/unity-ios-build-size-is-way-big) helps you. It contains good hints, but not accepted answer.

Comment: `Does it have anything to do with that I imported a variety of assets and plugins from assets store?` -> **yes**, there are certain things like shaders etc which might be attached to the build even though not present in the scene. Maybe relative: https://blogs.unity3d.com/ru/2018/05/14/stripping-scriptable-shader-variants and https://forum.unity.com/threads/absolutely-very-shader-gets-compiled-on-build-unused-ones-incuded.532285/

Comment: Are you building in release or development mode? Development build creates quite some overhead aswel. Also remove assets that you arn't using. Although they may not be used in the scene they may still be included in the build.

Comment: @KYL3R It still does not work.

Comment: @derHugo I delete those unused assets but did not make much difference. I only reduced the installation file size a little. It is still far larger than I expect.

Comment: @remy_rm I build it in release mode and I remove all the unused assets. Most of the remain assets are textures. The final file size is still too large which is around 200MB.